# Can we really put as well not only in the end of the sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms, idioms-in-context

My question is a bit similar to this discussion: [use-of-as-well-in-the-beginning-of-a-sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/431007/use-of-as-well-in-the-beginning-of-a-sentence). However, I still didn't get a clear answer to the related problem. I want the *firm answer* whether it's allowed or not.

According to [Merriam- Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/as%20well), there's an example when they put **as well** *in the middle*. It says:

> We might **as well** check out some local attractions while we're in town.

As we know, Merriam-Webster always provides synonyms to the words we are looking for. And the synonym mentions **also**. In this case, I assume **as well** can be replaced by also, what's more synonymous to **too**.

Nevertheless, after asking this problem to my senior (a person in my English group), he said perhaps I mistakenly considered it as an idiom **might as well** or **may as well** (wich has different meaning) and conviced me if **as well** always goes in the end of the sentence; yet I believe that the example sentence I've quoted above is discussing about **as well** that synonymous with (also/too).

By the way, here's the link about idiom Might/may as well I'm talking about: [idiom might may as well](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/might%2Fmay%20as%20well)

Comment: The first link you gave seems clear. In Canadian usage it might start a sentence, elsewhere it wouldn't. And no, your senior is confusing the conversation by talking about "might as well"; you're asking about the usage synonymous with "also." It can be in the middle of a sentence as long as it's at the end of a *clause*: "He brought some food. He brought a pan as well, to cook it."

Comment: In American usage I would **never** have the first two words of a sentence be "As well" meaning "also." (Having the first word be "Also" sounds a little awkward but is relatively common.) But some people do drop the "Might" in "Might as well" and then the sentence does start with "As well," but *only* as part of that idiom, not with the meaning "also."

Comment: Your quoted sentence contains 'might as well' which is a fixed expression, and any 'rule' about 'as well' (meaning also) going at the end of the sentence would not apply therefore. There is no such rule, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You may as well serve dinner now.
- You might as well service dinner now.

The Merriam Webster example is "not in the middle". It is actually using the idiom.

That is an idiomatic usage where the idiom "may as well" means: do something in a situation that has been frustrating or annoying.

**WHEREAS**

as well on its own just means "and also do some other thing". It is usually only used in speaking and not in formal writing.

Example:
Person 1: I'm going to clean up this room right now!
Person 2: Do the bathroom as well. [too.]

That usage can never some at the beginning of a sentence, though it might come in the middle:

Person 1: I'm leaving the dirty dishes in the sink for you (to wash).
Person 2: You can leave the glasses as well but take those dirty sneakers off the kitchen table.

[Please note: as well as x is a comparative and not related to what is explained above.]

Answer (score 0):

> However, I still didn't get a clear answer to the related problem. I want the *firm answer* whether it's allowed or not.

Some people will be happy to tell you that you can or can't do X, Y, Z but unfortunately, these types of rules doesn't exist in English (there's no equivalent to the [Académie Française](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_Fran%C3%A7aise))— as with most things, it's down to a matter of style or preference.

But in my opinion, "as well" can be used anywhere —

- **At the start of a sentence:** "I was sick last week, but I'm feeling great today. As well as I ever have!"
- **At the end of a sentence:** "If you go to the shops get some milk and some bread as well."
- **In the middle of a sentence:** "I did up the whole bathroom myself. I painted the ceiling as well as the walls, retiled the floor and changed the taps."